# CakePHP 4 checkbox not outputting value

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am using CakePHP 4.3.

According to [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-checkboxes), the option `value` can be used to set the value of the `"value"` HTML attribute.

Here's my code:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <?= $this->Form->checkbox('add_' . $item->id, [
        'id' => 'add_' . $item->id,
        'label' => false,
        'hiddenField' => false,
        'value' => $item->id,
    ]) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And here's the output on the page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add_1000936" value="1" id="add_1000936">
```

Of course I get multiple checkboxes because of the foreach, but that's beside the point. The problem is that all the checkboxes have value `"1"`.

While this is what I would expect:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add_1000936" value="1000936" id="add_1000936">
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is CakePHP somehow bugged?

If I do

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?= $item->id ?>" name="add_<?= $item->id ?>" id="add_<?= $item->id ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

instead, I get the correct output.

Comment: Looking at the cakePHP 4.x documentation and my own code it looks like the snippet you provided is the correct syntax. It looks almost like cake is taking the value as the boolean to determine if its checked. Try adding 'checked' => 0 to your checkbox options and see if that does anything?

Answer (score 0):

Go further down your link, you will see multiple checkbox example as below:
Form input

```
$options = [
    'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
    'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
];
echo $this->Form->select('field', $options, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
]);
```

Output form as array

```
<input name="field" value="" type="hidden">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="field-1">
        <input name="field[]" value="Value 1" id="field-1" type="checkbox">
        Label 1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="field-2">
        <input name="field[]" value="Value 2" id="field-2" type="checkbox">
        Label 2
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have read the examples, and tried them, the problem is that my code doesn't output what the examples show it should.